Надо ли выделять запятыми "конечно" в таких предложениях?
Тур состоится по многим городам: Москва, Волгоград, Рязань, Казань, Архангельск, Вологда, Петрозаводск и, конечно, Санкт-Петербург.

Павильно:
Тур состоится по многим городам: Москва, Волгоград, Рязань, Казань, Архангельск, Вологда, Петрозаводск и конечно Санкт-Петербург.
Пояснение
Слово конечно может быть вводным словом или частицей, и выбор в конечном итоге зависит от семантики и структуры конкретного предложения; также он может быть авторским.
В данном случае конечно относится к последнему члену однородного ряда, имеет значение уверенности и поэтому является частицей. Ударение переходит на конец предложения, и последний член интонационно подчеркнут.
В этой позиции часто используется и конечно же с усилительной частицей ЖЕ.
Карта слов
Открывая в своих детях таланты, вы помогаете им становиться сильнее, умнее и конечно добрее!
Ты активна и надёжна, корректна, вежлива и конечно же уверена в себе.
Без всякого сомнения, в приезжем хватало сил и конечно же активности.
